# Import an Image Folder into one Image Field

Tags: 7, media, importing-exporting

I've searched a lot for my problem, but I haven't found an answer yet.

I want to achieve, that if somebody uploads a whole folder of images per FTP, it should be possible to select the folder during the creation of a new node and add them into one image field.

It must be somehow like the file_attach module of drupal 6.
But for Drupal 7 and for whole directories instead of single files.
Does anybody has a guess or solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

It will most likely involve implementing the Drupal [File API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/group/file/7) in combination with the [Field API](http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/drupal-core/fields) in your custom module. I can't write a full implementation for you here because honestly it would take at least an hour to do it correctly, and still my example could miss your use case. But if you have a good handle of PHP and Drupal, you should be able to do it with the two APIs I mentioned above.